# LINQ: Sum from M-M table

Tags: c#, linq

Inside my M-M table I have `Quantity`(int) of a product for a specific order.

I'm trying to calculate Total of Quantity of same ProductId, disregard OrderId. Meaning I want to Sum all Quantity of a specific product within my List collection.

```
Product_Order:
    ---------------- ----------- ---------
    |   ProductId   | OrderId   | Quantity |
    ---------------- ----------- ---------
```

This is what I had in mind(code wont work):

```
SumQuantity = collection.Sum(x=> x.Product_Order
                         .Where(c=>c.ProductId == product.ID)
                         .Select(Quantity))
```

(collection-list is a list of products selected product that I added)

Comment: what is Product_Order ?

Comment: @MaksimSimkin It's a table that uses `Product.ID` and `Order.ID` (m-m relation). Also, it got a `Quantity` property which is amount of same product that is added in an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand, your `Quantity` is a property of `Product_Order`. So you need `collection` just to restrict your product Ids.
I would suggest to use this query:

```
var SumQuantity = Product_Order.Where(x=>collection.Any(o=>o.ProductId==x.ProductId))
                       .Sum(x=>x.Quantity);
```

Or if you do have `Quantity` on your `Product` Entitiy and want to use this one:

```
var SumQuantity = collection.Where(x=>Product_Order.Any(o=>o.ProductId==x.ProductId))
                   .Sum(x=>x.Quantity);
```

Comment: Thanks. If there's none, will it result 0 or null?

Comment: @fagol it will be 0, Result is not nullable int.

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure the Linq like this

```
collection.Where(c => c.Product_Order.ProductId == product.ID).Select(x => x.Product_Order.Quantity).Sum();
```

Comment: I can't access Quantity as you mentioned. I have to get past `Product_Order` somehow: `collection.Where(c => c.ID == product.ID).Select(x => x.Product_Order`..??..`).Sum();` . Not sure how to do it.

Comment: I couldnt add `ProductId` at `Product_Order.ProductId`. It just listed e.g. Count, Add, Remove etc.. This is how I made my collection list: `ICollection<Product> collection = (from order in orderFilter from item in order.Product_Order select item.Product).ToList();`.

Answer (score 0):

if Product_Order.Product is a list then you can try this

```
collection.Where(c => c.Product_Order.Product.Any(p=>p.id == product.ID)).Select(x => x.Product_Order.Quantity).Sum();
```